# Anime about a pirate submarine on a flooded mars

Tags: story-identification, anime

Around 5 to 10 Years ago I had seen an anime series that was set on Mars, which was flooded to create pretty much an ocean world.

The main character - a stereotypical male teen ditz - was picked up by a pirate submarine close to the start and in the run of the show, this pirate submarine did go on some kind of odyssey around the planet. I remember that the main character (oh wonder) proved to be the key to some ages-old mystery that would save the mankind of mars or something.

A particular scene that I remember relatively clearly was when the main cast did visit a *preserve* for *native* martian humans, that turned out to be pretty much a farce: behind the surface of primitive life (think like a native American preserve), the huts were stuffed with all the amenities of the *modern* martian life.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This appears to be [Mars Daybreak](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Anime/MarsDaybreak)

It hits all the main points:

- Ocean terraformed Mars
- Young male protagonist
- Invited onto crew of pirate submarine named 夜明けの船 / Yoake-no-fune. That would translate as *Vessel of Breaking Dawn* or (as the official translation) *Ship of Aurora*

> With the surface under heavy satellite surveillance, the pirates have been forced underground. Or rather, underwater. Instead of sailing over the waves, they lurk under them in submarines. And the baddest pirates around are the crew of the **sub** Ship of Aurora.
>
> Which brings us to our hero, Gram River: A young man living on the city-ship Adena. While trying to help a friend get out of a bad situation, he ends up in the middle of a raid by the Ship of Aurora, and thrown overboard when the port is rammed and breached... He is eventually hired on by the crew - https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Anime/MarsDaybreak

And from Wikipedia:

> The ocean-covered environment makes a perfect setting for commercial trade ships and **pirates to utilize submarines to make a living**. At the same time, the pirates also raid those very trades for personal profit. **The most renowned and feared of the pirate vessels is the Ship of Aurora**, which makes a habit of reselling its booty cheap so that it can be redistributed to the less fortunate folk. - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Daybreak

[image]

Comment: "ship of aurora..". is pretty much a translation error I believe: 夜明けの船 is the title as far as wikipedia tells, Yoake-no-fune. That would translate as "Vessel of Breaking Dawn"

Comment: Aurora is the Latin word for "dawn".

Comment: So is this like Space Pirate Captain Harlock, only on Mars?

Comment: @chepner the error is in the Ship/vessel distinction: Submarines in the English language are not ships but either the neutral *vessels* or (regardless of size) *boats*.